# What does the term "Tuple" Mean in Relational Databases?

Tags: sql, terminology, rdbms, definition, tuples

Please explain what is meant by tuples in sql?Thanks..

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Most of the answers here are on the right track.  However, a **row is not a tuple**.  **Tuples**`*` are *unordered* sets of known values with names.  Thus, the following tuples are the same thing (I'm using an imaginary tuple syntax since a relational tuple is largely a theoretical construct):

```
(x=1, y=2, z=3)
(z=3, y=2, x=1)
(y=2, z=3, x=1)
```

...assuming of course that x, y, and z are all integers.  Also note that there is no such thing as a "duplicate" tuple.  Thus, not only are the above equal, they're the *same thing*.  Lastly, tuples can only contain known values (thus, no nulls).

A **row**`**` is an ordered set of known or unknown values with names (although they may be omitted).  Therefore, the following comparisons return false in SQL:

```
(1, 2, 3) = (3, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 2) = (2, 1, 3)
```

Note that there are ways to "fake it" though.  For example, consider this `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO point VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

Assuming that x is first, y is second, and z is third, this query may be rewritten like this:

```
INSERT INTO point (x, y, z) VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

Or this:

```
INSERT INTO point (y, z, x) VALUES (2, 3, 1)
```

...but all we're really doing is changing the ordering rather than removing it.

And also note that there may be unknown values as well.  Thus, you may have rows with unknown values:

```
(1, 2, NULL) = (1, 2, NULL)
```

...but note that this comparison will always yield `UNKNOWN`.  After all, how can you know whether two unknown values are equal?

And lastly, rows may be duplicated.  In other words, `(1, 2)` and `(1, 2)` may compare to be equal, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they're the same thing.

If this is a subject that interests you, I'd highly recommend reading [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596523068) by CJ Date.

`*` Note that I'm talking about tuples as they exist in the relational model, which is a bit different from mathematics in general.

`**`And just in case you're wondering, just about everything in SQL is a row or table.  Therefore, `(1, 2)` is a row, while `VALUES (1, 2)` is a table (with one row).

**UPDATE**:  I've expanded a little bit on this answer in a blog post [here](http://jasonmbaker.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/the-relational-model-of-tuples-relations-rows-and-tables/).

Comment: Hello, I've read your answer and I've read similar answers on SO (Mike Samuel on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212265/tuples-vs-records/679449) and sampson-chen on [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057663/what-is-the-difference-between-a-row-record-and-tuple)) as well as [here](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/1251/tuple-database) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), and all say that tuples are **ordered** sets, not unordered. Your answer therefore confuses me.

Comment: I am just going through this now, but if a row has a primary key which is unique, does that not make every row unique in that way? No matter how it is ordered?

Comment: Basic question: `(x=1, y=2, z=3)` is 1 tuple or 3 tuples?

Comment: I don't get how (1, 2, 3) = (3, 2, 1) is not equal in SQL, a bad thing? I mean surely, they are two different things, assuming x = 3, y = 2, and z =1. I think the answer could be more clarified by not omitting name in your SQL example. I'm really confused even after reading your blog

Comment: This answer fails to distinguish the different meanings of the term "tuple" by default in mathematics (ordered) vs in relational database contexts (unordered name-value pair sets). It would also help if you distinguished between expressions what they denote. Eg "1/2" & "3/6" are two different expresssions that denote the fractional value one half, ie 1/2. It would also help if you distinguished between equality of values and the SQL operator `=` that treats the value NULL specially. Eg per the previous distinction between expresssions & denotations, `x = y` doesn't mean x equals y.

Answer (score 15):

It's a shortened "`N-tuple`" (like in `quadruple`, `quintuple` etc.)

It's a row of a rowset taken as a whole.

If you issue:

```
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    mytable
```

, whole result will be a `ROWSET`, and each pair of `col1, col2` will be a `tuple`.

Some databases can work with a tuple as a whole.

Like, you can do this:

```
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    mytable
WHERE   (col1, col2) =
        (
        SELECT  col3, col4
        FROM    othertable
        )
```

, which checks that a whole `tuple` from one `rowset` matches a whole `tuple` from another `rowset`.

Answer (score 4):

In **relational databases**, tables are [**relations** (in mathematical meaning)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)). Relations are sets of tuples. Thus table row in relational database is tuple in relation.

Wiki on relations:

> In mathematics (more specifically, in
>   set theory and logic), a relation is a
>   property that assigns truth values to
>   combinations (k-tuples) of k
>   individuals. Typically, the property
>   describes a possible connection
>   between the components of a k-tuple.
>   For a given set of k-tuples, a truth
>   value is assigned to each k-tuple
>   according to whether the property does
>   or does not hold.

Comment: Jason, vartec said the opposite: 
table row in relational database is tuple in relation"

Comment: He did also say "tables are relations (in mathematical meaning)."  Perhaps I should have said "Tables *aren't* relations".  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Whatever its use in mathematics, a tuple in RDBMS is commonly considered to be a row in a table or result set. In an RDBMS a tuple is unordered. A tuple in an MDDBMS is the instance of data in a cell with its associated dimension instances (members).

What is the tuple in a column family data store?

Answer (score 2):

tuple = 1 record; n-tuple = ordered list of 'n' records; Elmasri Navathe book (page 198 3rd edition).

record = either ordered or unordered.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it a table has a set K of keys and a typing function T with domain K. A row, or "tuple", of the table is a function r with domain K such that r(k) is an element of T(k) for each key k. So the terminology is misleading in that a "tuple" is really more like an associative array.

Answer (score -1):

row from a database table

Comment: Is it a row in a database table or any row in any set? If you create a projection from multiple tables, views, etc., is each row a tuple too?

Comment: A tuple may be a sub set of the row

Comment: AFAIK, a row in a resultset - this could be all the fields from one table, from multiple tables, views, etc.

Comment: @Tom Carter - A row may be a subset of the row as well.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

> > Tuples are known values which is used to relate the table in relational DB.

Answer (score -1):

Tuple is used to refer to a row in a relational database model. But tuple has little bit difference with row.

Answer (score -2):

A tuple is used to define a slice of data from a cube; it is composed of an ordered collection of one member from one or more dimensions. A tuple is used to identify specific sections of multidimensional data from a cube; a tuple composed of one member from each dimension in a cube completely describes a cell value.

Comment: In the relational model, tuples aren't ordered:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Relational_model